# Just read a Register

Tags: microcontroller, stm32, c, i2c

I am using a STM32F103CBT6 as I2C Master. After sending the I2C Adress of the Slave I need to clear the Addr bit in the SR1 register. The Datasheet states:

"ADDR: Address sent (master mode)/matched (slave mode)
This bit is cleared by software reading SR1 register followed reading SR2"

Therefore i have two lines after the busy wait loop checking for the bit like this:

```
uint16_t a = I2C1->SR1;
uint16_t b = I2C1->SR2;
```

This works fine and the compiler won't optimize the reads, because the Registers are declared as `volatile`, but it warns me as the two variables are never read and therefore useless. I would like to get rid of these warnings. Is it guaranteed to work, when i change the lines like this:

```
I2C1->SR1;
I2C1->SR2;
```

Or should i clear the bit manually without reading SR2 ever ?

Thanks in Advance

Comment: This is pretty much an StackOverfow question. But yes, if these are volatile it should work. Alternatively you can put `(void)a; (void)b;` in the body of the function to silence the warnings.

Comment: Actually no. Looks like it is not working as you propose: https://arm.godbolt.org/z/vljOTL . Probably because `p;` does not imply the access type to `p` (read or write).

Comment: When I add an Asterix infront of the p it generates a ldr instruction.

Comment: Hm. Yeah, it should be tested this way. Still not sure about if it is guaranteed to translate to a read instruction. A valid, and probably a good question for SO, if formulated properly.

Comment: See here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53658582/is-volatile-t0x1234-guaranteed-to-translate-into-read-instruction

Answer (score 1):

The usual way to do this, safely and portably:

```
volatile uint16_t dummy = I2C1->SR1;
(void)dummy;
```

This usually works even on dysfunctional compilers. If the compiler still warns, you need to file a bug report to the compiler vendor.

Answer (score 0):

If you can clear the bit manually, doing so would make your code clearer. If the only way to clear the bit is to read the registers, then a good way to do it is:

```
//Reading SR1 and SR2 automatically clears the ADDR bit
(void)I2C1->SR1;
(void)I2C1->SR2;
```

which makes it obvious for future readers that you really do want to read the variable and ignore its value. As long as I2C1 is a pointer to a volatile structure (which it is), the compiler will do what you expect.

Comment: I wouldn't recommend this - the C standard is quite vague here and many compilers also behave badly when just given a volatile identifier on a single line.